# javascript nested foreach loops and this

Tags: javascript, foreach, this

I have nested foreach loops and I want to access the index of the parent within the child. Normally I would know how to do this but I have abstracted* the callback functions so I can use them in other parts of my program. 
I assume this has something to do with `this` but I can't figure it out.

*what is the right word here?

the following code is what I have tried

```
const processChildArray = function( value, index ){
    console.log( `${this.index} ${index} ${value}` );
}

const processParentArray = function( value, index ){
    value.childArray.forEach( processChildArray, this )
}

parentArray.forEach( processParentArray );
```

but it says index is undefined

Comment: you mean it says `this.index` is undefined?

Comment: do you have some data?

Comment: `this.index` in `processChildArray` is `processParentArray`'s `this` in that scenario. `this.index` will be undefined, because the function arguments of `processParentArray` are **NOT** binded to the the `processParentArray`'s `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in processChildArray is not what you want it to be

One solution is to bind the outer index to the processChildArray call

```js
const processChildArray = function( pIndex, value, index ){
    console.log( `${pIndex} ${index} ${value}` );
}

const processParentArray = function( value, index ){
    value.childArray.forEach( processChildArray.bind(null, index) )
}

const parentArray = [{childArray:[1,2]},{childArray:[3,4]}];
parentArray.forEach( processParentArray );
```

Note when binding a function like this, the bound argument will be FIRST, then the arguments from `forEach` callback

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of your data but I think this might help

```js
parentArray.forEach(function(entry) {
  entry.childArray.forEach(function(childrenEntry, index) {
    console.log(`${entry.index} ${index} ${childrenEntry}`);
  });
});
```

Comment: the issue with for each loop is you can't break it in between if you have 50 parents with 10 children each then it will run for 50 X 10 = 500 times. instead, you can replace your loops by more efficient array methods.